# Making specific text bold in a string in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I want make some specific part of a  string in bold and bigger in size. Given below is the string.

```
{
-----
-----
    string body = "TICKET \n";body += "Category : " + Category + "\n";
    body += "Priority : " + priority + "\n";body += "Type : " + type + "\n";
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
    smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object
    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
}
```

From the above string, I want to make specific part bold and larger in size. I want `TICKET` should be bolder and bigger. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Comment: are you displaying the content in textbox?

Comment: @Sajeetharan : Some parts are taking from text box and some are simply typed inside double quotes. I want make the text typed inside double quotes (ie,"Ticket") as bold.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is,

```
string body = "<span style='font-weight:bold;font-size:25px;'>TICKET</span> \n";body += "Category : " + Category + "\n";
body += "Priority : " + priority + "\n";body += "Type : " + type + "\n";
```

I have update your code, please use it.

```
string body = "TICKET \n"; body += "Category : " + "Category" + "\n";
    body += "Priority : " + "priority" + "\n"; body += "Type : " + "type" + "\n";

    MailMessage objMailMessage = new MailMessage();
    System.Net.NetworkCredential objSMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
    SmtpClient objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();

    objMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
    objMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));
    objMailMessage.Subject = subject;
    objMailMessage.Body = body;
    objMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

    objSmtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    objSmtpClient.Port = 587;
    objSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    objSmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    objSmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
    objSmtpClient.Timeout = 20000;

    objSmtpClient.Send(objMailMessage);
```

Comment: Where are you rendering "string body" variable?

Comment: I want to send this content in a mail. There I want to display the ticket as bolder and bigger.

Comment: If you are sending email using "MailMessage" class then please allow "MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;" in your code.

Comment: Added MailMessage.IsBodyHtml='true'. But it shows an error. The error is "MailMessage' does not contain a definition for 'IsBodyHtml'"

Comment: I have update my answer and added send email method for you, just pass your parameters in this method and check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73985/discussion-between-dexterity-and-reshma).

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

From the '\n' character beside your "TICKET", I presume you want to make it the title text of your document.

To do this, I would simply surround the title text with a 'h4' HTML tag like below:

```
string body = "<h4>TICKET</h4>";body += "Category : " + Category + "\n";
body += "Priority : " + priority + "\n";body += "Type : " + type + "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what your trying to display it in. If you are trying to display the string in a label, textbox, etc. You can use the properties window, in visual studio, select the label, textbox etc, then click on the font cell, click on the ... next to it and it lets you bold/change font style/size. Hope this helps.